# MS Excel wrongly converts long number into Engineering unit

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a downloaded CSV file which when opened in MS excel the data is wrong but when opened in other editors like Notepad++ its correct.

For example a number 78487487874878787487 is wrongly converted by Excel as 7.84875E+19. On selecting this cell it shows the value as 78487487874878700000.

But I expected 78487487874878787487 the original content instead of 78487487874878700000. Excel converts the last 5 digits to 00000.

I have attached a screen shot.

Any work around please ?

[image]
File source:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpbiyh7ysjfmdyp/download.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the cell format as `Text`:

`Right click` the target column (in your case "B") or a particular cell -> `Format Cells` -> choose `Text`

Or prepend the number with a single quote: `'78487487874878787487`

As shown below:

[image: screenshot]

**Edit**:
Another method:

1. Open the `CSV` file in `Notepad++`
2. Select All (`ctrl + a`)
3. Copy it (`ctrl + c`)
4. Open a `New` MS Excel File
5. select Column 1 and Row 1 of excel
6. Paste (`ctrl + v`)
7. Select Column A
8. Go to `Data` in excel tab options
9. Click on `Text to Columns`
10. Seelct radio option `Delimited`
11. Next and then select only `Comma`
12. Next and Change Column Data Type to `Text` for `Entity Code` i.e.
     2nd Column
13. `Finish`

**Step.10 Delimited:**

[image: delimited]

**Step.12 Text:**

[image: text]

**It is done**. Now the numbers in the 2nd column will be displayed full as text: `78487487874878787487`.

Comment: Thanks. But once you open the file in Excel the number is already tampered and last five digits changed to 00000. Even though we format the cell to text it does not bring back the original value.

Comment: You should somehow format the excel cells before you enter the data in those cells. Another option would be to prepend all the numbers with `'` in notepad++.

Comment: Thanks. Its a downloaded CSV file from the net. And after downloading when I opened it opens in the default excel editor.

Comment: I checked your csv file. Do you have many such records or just one?

Comment: That's just a sample... we have many such records...and its a dynamic records that people download from web application online...according to their search results..

Comment: I tried opening this CSV file in a Free Office on Linux and then changed the cell format as `Text` and it looked better `78487487874878783488` it got rounded at last digit. You could also try other free office suits. Otherwise you would need to prepend all such number with `'` in CSV file: you can write a `C` or `Python` program to do it for you.

Comment: That's perfect many many thanks for the great effort, it worked. A small difference we did is we started by saving the file as .txt file and opened in excel and followed the wizard as you have captured in screen shot. Its quite messy for the end user but seems no other simple way possible and they have to follow these steps.

Comment: Thanks, you just made me to cross 1 K rep :)

Comment: Congrats for the milestone :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only about the incorrect display, following link should solve your problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2643223

Comment: Thanks. Its not just the display. The first main problem is the tampered data with last 5 digits changed to 00000 by Excel.